# Inserting millions of records from local to godaddy hosting

Tags: java, php, mysql, ms-access, laravel-5

I'm trying to insert about 8 million records from an access database to a mysql database in GoDaddy.

I built a desktop java app to manage the inserts chunking 5000 records each time. I use Laravel 5.1 to manage the inserts in the server. So, basically, the java app send a request to a laravel php route, then it take care of inserting directly in my MySQL database.

Edit: people will insert data directly into the Access, so I have to watch the MDB file for changes. This is why I can't just export from Access and import into the MySQL.

The first part of records inserts successfully, but than when I send another request, I get this error:

```
2015-10-28 10:43:57.844 java[3475:280209] Communications error: <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x7fff7298bb90> { count = 1, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x7fff7298bf40> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }
}>
Got xpc error message: Connection interrupted
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: api.mydomain.com:80 failed to respond
```

Comment: How long is the request until it errors? That could happen if the request times out.

Comment: Do you have ssh access to the server the database is on?

Comment: Why not just generate an insert statement for every 2000 records and run them one at a time? Inserting into the database will be far more efficient. Using laravel to insert the records is going to take far more resources and time...
Worst case, have your php execute the statement if you don't have direct access to the DB- but don't load things into Eloquent models and insert them individually.

Comment: If i were you, I'd insert only a few of them at once, then reopen the connection and write another pack of them. 8 million records seems way too much to me.

Comment: It's not a time request error. It's ok with that. @satisfaction

Comment: Letting aside technical details I would go and hide your red, sweet and sticky employer from your error logs posted...

Comment: I'll try to send less request Mikel Bitson.

Comment: I still didn't get the ssh. I'll also try it to insert directly. @Ranker

Comment: do you have MS Access installed? why using java and all those if you can do it with Access alone?

Comment: Krish, I thought about it too. But I don't know how to do that. Do you have some links about it?

Comment: Jan, thanks for the observation!!! Hurry...you know...

Comment: what version do you have installed? i will post an  answer to that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have MySQL odbc connector is installed:
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/

create your DNS to your MySQL server (you can do this via odbc manager or just with a notepad)
your DNS file will look like this:

```
[ODBC]
DRIVER=MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver ' check what driver is installed
UID=username to the server
PORT=3306
PWD= password to the server
DATABASE=dbname
SERVER=serverip/name
```

Save the DNS file somewhere lets call it GoDaddy_MySQL.dns

Open up you ACCESS database.

1. External Data
2. ODBC
3. Select "link to the data source by creating"
4. select the godaddy_mysql.dns file
5. if all your connection details are correct Access will show you tables & views to import. Click the tables you would like to upload data from your Access dtabase.
6. Now you have linked the actual MySQL table in your MS Access database.

All you need to do is uploading data from your local table to your linked table simply by:

you can chunk your upload by using the TOP keyword. if you add a where condition with (is not already on the linked table) you can always upload new records automatically to your MySQL server.

if you are and will still use your Access database you can also switch from local to linked tables so all new entry will automatically uploaded to your godaddy server.

```
Pseudo: 

insert into linked_table select top 5000 from your local table where local_records_are not in linked table.
```

Comment: Thanks Krish KM! U'r awesome!

Comment: Just for sure...If I let this options enabled, when I close Access and data was inserted (by another program for example), does it still works? I tested yesterday just inserting and connecting. PS.: Sorry! I don't know Access very well..

Comment: didn't get your question: The godaddy MySQL table in your MS Access is a mirror of you godaddy server. so yes, you will see all godaddy records in your ms access when someone else inserts in godaddy. and vise versa.

Comment: Nice!! Understood!! Tk u! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try a staggered MySQL importer that is run on the GoDaddy server. Like Bigdump: http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/

[Export from Access](http://ccm.net/faq/7342-export-access-database-to-mysql), import to MySQL. It's run directly on the godaddy server, so the data is already on the server and then just read. I've used this numerous times on GoDaddy for large imports.

Cheers!

Comment: Mikel, I can't do that, because people will insert data in the access first, so I'll have to watch the Access file for changes.

Comment: Ah, this is an ongoing sync? Not a transfer?